# modifying a public static final array

Tags: java, arrays, final

While designing a small API, i was about to write a static value that references to an array of String:
`public static final String[] KEYS={"a","b","c"}`
I have found this to be marked as a 'security hole' in Joshua Bloch's 'Effective Java' item 14, where he proposes as an alternative, declaring te array 'private' and provide a public getter that returns an unmodifiable list:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(KEYS))
```

I just cant see why would this be necessary, the array in the initial statement is declared final even though its public, and its elements are immutable, how could that be modified from an external piece of code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The array is not immutable.

You can still write:

```
KEYS[0] = "d";
```

without any issues.
`final` just means you cannot write:

```
KEYS = new String[]{"d"};
```

I.e. you cannot assign a new value to the variable `KEYS`.

Comment: Upvoted for explaining `final`, seems like a lot of people don't understand that keyword.

Answer (score 5):

*final* means

> You can't change the Basket. Still you can change the fruits inside.

Basket is your Array instance. Fruits are your keys inside.

In first case, from somewhere else in the code, I can do

```
ClassName.KEYS[2] ="MyOwnValue";
```

But you can't modify when it is unmodifiable list.

Give a shot to read : [Why final instance class variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049697/why-final-instance-class-variable-in-java)

Comment: Nice analogy, I love it :)

Answer (score 0):

While the array reference itself is immutable (you cannot replace it with a reference to another array) and the Strings themselves are immutable too it is still possible to write

```
KEYS[0] = "new Key";
```

Answer (score 0):

A composite object ( array , `Set` , `List` etc ) being `final` doesn't mean that its constituent objects will not be changed - you can still change constituent objects . `final` for a composite object simply means that its reference can't be changed.

For your case, value of `KEYS` can't be changed but `KEYS[0]` etc can be changed.